# Look back through Pandas Dataframe for previous entry given certain value

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to teach myself python so this question is more general than specific but I would really appreciate some pointers! I want to know how to loop through a dataframe, performing a calculation on each row where I add one of the column values to a value in a previous row with the same features. By way of example, say I have the following df:

```
      date    order_id    price    cust_id
0 2020-05-01       101   10.5      A1
1 2020-06-03       102  116.3      A2
2 2020-06-04       103   58.4      A3
3 2020-06-05       104   62.5      A1
4 2020-06-06       105   40.2      A1
5 2020-11-10       106   15.6      A4
6 2020-11-15       107   89.4      A5
7 2020-11-20       108   72.1      A6
8 2020-11-21       109   53.6      A5
9 2020-11-22       110   14.5      A4
```

I want to create a new column "rtotal" which gives a running total of the value of a particular customers orders to date. I have been trying all sorts of different ways but am getting nowhere. I have been trying along these lines:

```
df=df.assign(rtotal="")
for i in range (0, len(df)):
           df.rtotal[i] = df['price'].iloc[i] + df.loc[df['cust_id'].shift(-1)== df.cust_id[i], 'rtotal']
```

The two issues I am having is firstly how to deal with the rows where a new cust_id appears (i.e. it is their first order so no previous values exist) and how to get the loop to look at the last value with same cust_id, take the rtotal for that and then add the price of the current order.

As I said I'm trying to learn how I would go about a general problem like this and not just this particular problem so any pointers really gratefully received!

Comment: One thing about pandas is that they have inbuilt functions for most of the tasks so you can try to avoid looping through and doing calculations yourself. For example, in your case, for a rolling sum, we have `.cumsum()` and since you want to sum each cust_id, you have `groupby`. Try not to loop and look for functions.

Comment: And even after this, if you do end up looping, you should do `for index,row in df.iterrows()`. This will save you a lot of the `.iloc[i]` and `.loc` etc. They have a function to help you look through as well :)

Comment: Thanks Shubham - will definitely bear this in mind in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try [groupby cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-cumsum):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2020-05-01', 1: '2020-06-03',
                            2: '2020-06-04', 3: '2020-06-05',
                            4: '2020-06-06', 5: '2020-11-10',
                            6: '2020-11-15', 7: '2020-11-20',
                            8: '2020-11-21', 9: '2020-11-22'},
                   'order_id': {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 103, 3: 104, 4: 105,
                                5: 106, 6: 107, 7: 108, 8: 109, 9: 110},
                   'price': {0: 10.5, 1: 116.3, 2: 58.4, 3: 62.5,
                             4: 40.2, 5: 15.6, 6: 89.4, 7: 72.1,
                             8: 53.6, 9: 14.5},
                   'cust_id': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'A3', 3: 'A1',
                               4: 'A1', 5: 'A4', 6: 'A5', 7: 'A6',
                               8: 'A5', 9: 'A4'}})

df['rtotal'] = df.groupby('cust_id')['price'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date  order_id  price cust_id  rtotal
0  2020-05-01       101   10.5      A1    10.5
1  2020-06-03       102  116.3      A2   116.3
2  2020-06-04       103   58.4      A3    58.4
3  2020-06-05       104   62.5      A1    73.0
4  2020-06-06       105   40.2      A1   113.2
5  2020-11-10       106   15.6      A4    15.6
6  2020-11-15       107   89.4      A5    89.4
7  2020-11-20       108   72.1      A6    72.1
8  2020-11-21       109   53.6      A5   143.0
9  2020-11-22       110   14.5      A4    30.1
```

---

(Sorted by `cust_id` so it's easier to see)

```py
df = df.sort_values('cust_id')
```

```
         date  order_id  price cust_id  rtotal
0  2020-05-01       101   10.5      A1    10.5
3  2020-06-05       104   62.5      A1    73.0
4  2020-06-06       105   40.2      A1   113.2
1  2020-06-03       102  116.3      A2   116.3
2  2020-06-04       103   58.4      A3    58.4
5  2020-11-10       106   15.6      A4    15.6
9  2020-11-22       110   14.5      A4    30.1
6  2020-11-15       107   89.4      A5    89.4
8  2020-11-21       109   53.6      A5   143.0
7  2020-11-20       108   72.1      A6    72.1
```